# Can I Flag a question asking a Tool which is off-topic in Pro Webmasters but asked 3 years ago and having an accepted answer?

Tags: discussion, off-topic, flagging

I found [this](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18498/how-to-keep-track-of-websites-updates) question is asking a tool that can provide details of quick updates/changes of some other websites to OP. As asking a tool is [off-topic](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) in Pro Webmasters. Can I flag this post as Off-topic? Why am I asking this question is that question was asked three years back and have an accepted answer. I don't know weather I can flag such questions?

> Recommendations for sites and resources -- Questions that ask for
>   recommendations of external websites or resources attract lots of self
>   promotion and spam answers. In addition, answers to such questions
>   quickly become out of date. Such questions are closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Absolutely.  A question can be flagged as off-topic no matter how old it is.

Moderators have special tool to deal with such situations.  You could suggest in your flag that that this be used:

> ### Lock
>
> #### Historical significance
>
> This question exists because it has historical significance, but it is not considered a good, on-topic question for this site, so please do not use it as evidence that you can ask similar questions here. This question and its answers are frozen and cannot be changed. More info: [help].

Comment: So do I need to suggest as above Blockquoted text while flagging such questions?

Comment: Select "other (needs ♦ moderator attention)" then say something like "off topic; lock for historical significance" would be fine.

Comment: Understood. Thanks @Stephen